# Scaling of probability for multivariate normal.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Say I have a multivariate normal given as:

$$f({\bf x})=f({\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}Q({\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2)\right] $$

where $Q$ is defined as 
$\displaystyle Q({\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2)$  $\textstyle =$  $\displaystyle ({\bf x}-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}({\bf x}-\mu)$ and where ${\bf x}_1$ and ${\bf x}_2$ are two subvectors of respective dimensions $p$ and $q$ with $p+q=n$. Note that  $\Sigma=\Sigma^T$, and  $\Sigma_{21}=\Sigma_{21}^T$ and

we can write

$$ f({\bf x})=f({\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2)= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{p/2} |\Sigma_{11}|^{1/2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(x_1-\mu_1)^T\Sigma_{11}^{-1}(x_1-\mu_1)\right]  \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{p/2} |A|^{1/2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(x_2-\mu_2)^TA^{-1}(x_2-\mu_2)\right] =  N({\bf x}_1,\mu_1,\Sigma_{11})\;N({\bf x}_2,b,A)$$

where the b is given as 
$$b\stackrel{\triangle}{=}\mu_2+\Sigma_{12}^T\Sigma_{11}^{-1}({\bf x}_1-\mu_1) $$

and the A as 
$$A\stackrel{\triangle}{=}\Sigma_{22}-\Sigma_{12}^T\Sigma_{11}^{-1}\Sigma_{12} $$

Now say I define $(x_1 ^{\alpha}, x_2^{\alpha})$ as $F( (x_1,x_2) \leq (x_1^{\alpha}, x_2^{\alpha}) ) > \alpha $. where F is the cumulative normal.

Given a $b$ is there a scaling relation of to figure out what  cumulative $ N( x_2^{\alpha},b,A)$ will be in terms of F and/or possibly some other factors.

Essentially I have split the multivariate normal into two parts. And if I know that cumulative probability of the whole part, I am trying to figure out how much of that comes from part one and how much comes from part two.